# How do you redirect from server to client using express/nodejs backend?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, google-oauth

Using MERN stack with a nodejs/express backend & react client...

Working on a school project, and trying incorporate Google's oAuth 2.0 so that students can log in with their school provided email. Google's oAuth returns a query string containing an Auth-code on the first request around(which I am doing from the client side via a button). Then you must exchange this Auth code for refresh & auth tokens. I want this first redirect round to route through the server so I can perform logic to only allow a sign in with the domain of our High school email accounts, which can be performed via req.query.hd. By that logic, on a get request, the routes of the server and user being redirected from google should match - where we can perform our logic, correct?

There, IF you do not sign in with the school email domain, I want the user to route back to the client side... and display a message depicting that "you did not login with the proper google acc".... How could this be accomplished?

Next (if email domain is a pass), making a put req in axios should handle the exchange of , I don't know that it's formatted correctly, but that is my next task to tackle. If there are any suggestions all together on a smoother process, I'd appreciate them! Only in high-school and learning independently so if code does not look proper, feel free to let me know. All help appreciated.

```
app.get("/signin/callback", (req, res, next) => {
    //declare vars from query string api return for later use
    console.log(req.query);
    let hd = req.query.hd;
    let authCode = req.query.code;

    if(hd == 'guhsd.net') {
        console.log('you are good to pass');
        next();
    } else {
        console.log('you are not good to pass')
        //REDIRECT TO REACT CLIENT ON PORT 3000 SAYING FAILED TO LOGIN 
        //BECAUSE YOU DID NOT SIGN IN WITH PROPER EMAIL ADDRESS
        //THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP/SUGGESTIONS TO REDIRECT BACK TO CLIENT 
        res.end;
    };    

    res.send('making a post to exchange auth code for tokens')
     axios.post('https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token', {
            client_id: "a string",
            client_secret: "a string",
            code: authCode,
            grant_type: "authorization_code",
            //google handles redirect to client... react running on port:3000
            redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000"
    });  
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has several fails, you are calling `next()` and continue calling to res.

To redirect you can use [res.redirect](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect) but first manage your flow:

```
app.get("/signin/callback", (req, res, next) => {
    //declare vars from query string api return for later use
    console.log(req.query);
    let hd = req.query.hd;
    let authCode = req.query.code;

    if(hd !== 'guhsd.net') {
        console.log('you are not good to pass')
        // The return is fot not continue executing the controller
        return res.redirect(301, '/signing/?error=invalid_domain');
    }

    // Why you send it to the client?
    // res.send('making a post to exchange auth code for tokens')

    axios.post('https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token', {
            client_id: "a string",
            client_secret: "a string",
            code: authCode,
            grant_type: "authorization_code",
            //google handles redirect to client... react running on port:3000
            redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000"
    })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log('Your token must to be here');
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('Error happend');
            next(error);
        });
 });
```

Comment: With that, I'm getting req. failed err code 400 from axios. Is this because of trying to pass through the authCode through in the way that I am?

Comment: 400 is "bad request", check if you are sending the correct body format to the api endpoint, or check the error message.

Comment: @DEVINPROVENCE Mmm you are getting the token in request, `redirect_uri` is to get the code in a frontend (not neccesary in your case), remove it option, and check that

Comment: I'm getting the response error of redirect_uri_mismatch with the redirect uri of localhost:3000.

You must include redirect_uri as a param, or you will get error saying invalid req with description of missing param: redirect uri. 

I do want to receive the JSON response with tokens on the clientside, and I want the user to be taken to the clientside with this req. I assumed the axios post request would be able to take the user with it and they would be redirected to the redirect_uri via google's logic. Now I'm thinking that is not the case...

Comment: ... I want to be able to follow this logic , redirect to frontend -> store json in cookie -> make req to server, interceptor logic, take token in cookie to server -> server receives req., valid? ask google, store via redis cache that times out with cookie -> On browser req, server handle, if fails refresh token logic... etc etc.. basically a progressive way that treats client and server 'sessions', so to speak, independently of eachother